# css position: fixed; disappearing issue

Tags: css

when ı set the position: fixed; div is disappearing so what can ı do

[Before code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XVWpu.jpg)
[Before Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3C7lm.jpg)

[After code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IVi9r.jpg) [After page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g37Ex.jpg)

Comment: can you show me your html code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I know what happens, for what I can see from the screenshots.

**Why?**
This happens because when you set a element 'fixed', their position is not relative to their parent any more. It is relative to the html document. You could also say it is taken out of the 'normal' content/document flow.

Since I miss some information on what you would like to achieve, a suggestion is using the value 'sticky' in the property 'position'. This will keep it inside the flow of the document and is 'fixed' relative to their parent. IF you want to achieve this and I would suggest reading into it because using it can be tricky.

**Example:**

```
.container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 90rem;
}

.container-child {
    position: sticky;
    top: 0; /* Needed, because this way you'll let the browser know when to get sticky when the viewport(top) of the user 'touches' the element. */
}
```

Source: [MDN position: sticky](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position#sticky)

Beware that the browser support is limited or quirky in some browsers.

I would also suggest setting a codepen example for your problems with a description of the expected behavior. That makes it easier to understand and replicate your issue. ;) https://codepen.io/